# How do you find the absolute position of a GTK widget in a window?

Tags: gtk

I can use GTK "allocation" function, but that only gives the position relative to its parent.  How does one find the absolute position of a GTK widget inside of a window?

Ie, if the widget appears 500 pixels in, and 300 pixels down, but is nested inside various hboxes and tables, how do we find out it is in a 500x300 pixel position?

I need to make a window appear in an exact place under another widget.

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `gtk_widget_translate_coordinates()` function to map from the coordinates of your child widget to the coordinates of the toplevel containing the widget. It might look something like

```
GtkWidget *somewidget;
gint wx, wy;
gtk_widget_translate_coordinates(somewidget, gtk_widget_get_toplevel(somewidget), 0, 0, &wx, &wy);
```

Note that in many cases forcing the position of a new window is a misfeature unless it's acting as a popup menu.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:

```
gint wx, wy;
gdk_window_get_origin (gtk_widget_get_window (somewidget), &wx, &wy);
```

Comment: This is absolute to the screen and no relative to the GTK window!